# Can I live in Ohio for a year while still remaining an Indiana resident?

Tags: united-states, ohio, residency, indiana

Say that I live in one state and have everything registered to that state (e.g., car insurance, health insurance, etc.), but I want to move to another state for one year and then come back. Would I be able to perform that move without undergoing the cost of transferring residency?

Answer (score 3):

"Residency" is not a single thing, for example "in-state tuition" is one way in which residency matters, fishing licenses are another, then there is voting, taxes, driver's licenses and so on. When you are absent from your permanent home, you don't lose your e.g. Indiana residency, but you may be required to pay taxes based on living in Ohio. As for income taxes, [here](https://tax.ohio.gov/individual/resources/residency-status) are the rules, but basically you will have to pay Ohio income tax at least for the part of a year that you live in Ohio. There is no additional charge involved in paying Ohio income taxes. You are [allowed to drive](https://codes.ohio.gov/ohio-administrative-code/rule-4501:1-1-35) in Ohio as a non-resident using your out of state license, and you are a non-resident (for the driver's license rule) because you are "a person who currently lives in Ohio, for temporary purposes only, with a specific intention to return to live in a different state or country of residence".

[BMV](https://www.bmv.ohio.gov/new-to-ohio.aspx) holds that "You are considered an Ohio resident once you: Take a job, Sign a lease, Buy a home, or Enroll children in school" so you would have to register your car, however they mis-state the driver's license rule for people living temporarily in the state. They will probably tell you that you have to transfer title and registration (at a cost) and while they are at it they will mention your driver's license (another fee), then back to Indiana a year later.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive reply. I was wondering if there are any exceptions to the BMV rules; for instance, many of the Ohio students I know have not registered their vehicle in Ohio because they are renting their apartments as students. I will be an online student but will not be living in Ohio for school anymore, so I am not sure if anything would apply to my situation.

Comment: You need to consider your auto insurance and where you will "garage" your car if you do not transfer the title to Ohio.